# How to generate numbers between two values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to generate numbers between 2 values, for example 15 numbers between 32 and 35.

I wrote this:

```
SELECT LEVEL+31 + round(dbms_random.value(1, 4))
FROM   dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=15;
```

but it gives me results like this:

```
 34
 36
 37
 36
 39
 39
 40
 41
 44
 44
 45
 47
 45
 47
 47
```

I want all 15 values to fall within the range 31 to 35.

Comment: In the first line of your question you say "between 32 and 35" and in the last line you say "range 31 to 35". Can you make up your mind? Other than that, do you want the numbers to be generated with (approximately) equal frequency? If YES, then note that the `round` function won't do that. You should be using `trunc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `LEVEL` from `SELECT` and modify *limits* in `dbms_random.value`:

```
SQL> select round(dbms_random.value(31, 35)) result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 15;

    RESULT
----------
        32
        31
        34
        32
        34
        31
        33
        32
        33
        32
        34
        34
        35
        33
        33

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Most likely, `round()` is also wrong in the OP's attempt. The end points (31 and 35) will be generated at half the frequency of the other values. The correct approach (assuming uniform distribution is desired) is to use `trunc()`. `dbms_random.value()` helps, because it generates values >= lower bound and < upper bound. For numbers between 31 and 35 (generated with equal likelihood), use `trunc(dbms_random.value(31, 36)` - note that the upper bound is 36, not 35.